# How to ignore only one line in svn?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn

I have a line of code in my Config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://{ComputerName}/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;StsEndpoint=https://{ComputerName}:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355" />
  </appSettings>
```

and you can see {ComputerName} there. This name depends on current computer name. And if i using some source control tool, i get a problem cause in other computer project doesn't run with my connectionString.

How can I avoid this problem?

I cann't ignore this file in svn cause i will be change in future and i can lose this changes.

maybe this problem can be solved on svn layer or in visual studio.

Comment: what if you change {ComputerName} by the actual computer name. Does it work ?

Comment: it works, but only on my computer. And if i commit this change in svn, on other commputers it doesn't work

Comment: I would say the problem is that you don't have the same config file. Everyone would need to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `localhost` instead of the computer name, or have that placeholder and replace it at runtime.

Or you could put this key into a separate config file which does not go into source control:

```
<!-- In your regular app.config/web.config -->
<appSettings file="user.config">
  <!-- You can have normal stuff here -->
</appSettings>

<!-- In a file called user.config -->
<appSettings>
  <add key="whatever" value="JoesMachine" />
</appSettings>
```

user.config would not be in source control at all, just would have to live on each person's machine. That's an extra step when you set up a new developer, but it might work for you. (If it's a Windows app, not a web app, make sure you set Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always on user.config in the project, so it makes its way into your bin directory.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't ignore a single line.

Generally when you have a configuration file that must be modified by everyone, you use [this approach](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit).

Since you're using Visual Studio, you can avoid this by creating different configurations for your builds & using those to modify the final configuration files at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Have placeholder text in the config, like it is now, and in code at initialization use Environment.MachineName to replace the placeholder text.  I would go so far as to assign the placeholder text as a config setting as well so you're never hardcoding it.